# Move semantics for a resource manager class

Tags: c++, c++11, resources, sfml, move-semantics

I am trying to make a resource class for my game (which makes use of the SFML API). 
Basically I first load the needed resources and then I just get references to them when needed in order to avoid the heavy construction of the resource classes.

(I will use the sf::Texture class as an example)

The problem lies in the load function.
In order to make an sf::Texture I have to use the default constructor and then use it's loadFromFile function to get the needed texture. Say I have a map containing pairs of the file names and the respective resources:

```
std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> textures;
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile(file);
```

Now if I do:

```
textures.emplace(file, texture);
```

This will use the copy-constructor to make another sf::Texture.
So I thought I should use std::move but apparently the sf::Texture class doesn't have a move constructor so this would still make a copy. In order to solve this I am now using a map containing pairs of the file names and the respective unique_pointers to the objects.
So I do:

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> texture(new sf::Texture);
texture->loadFromFile(file);
textures.emplace(file, std::move(texture));
```

Here is how the complete function looks like:

```
void ResourceManager::loadTexture(std::string file)
{
        std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> texture(new sf::Texture);
        if (!texture->loadFromFile(file))
        {
                throw std::runtime_error("ResourceManager::load - Failed to load " + file);
        }
        auto inserted = mtextures.emplace(file, std::move(texture));
        assert(inserted.second);
}
```

I don't have much experience with move semantics though and I am not sure if I got everything right. Basically, have I missed anything? If this question does not belong to stack overflow I will gladly move it to the appropriate site.

Comment: `apparently the sf::Texture class doesn't have a move constructor`. Indeed, SFML 2 is written in C++98.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've posted looks correct, given the description of what you're trying to do.

The map will be designated as the owner of the resource. When it is destroyed, the resource will be destroyed as well, unless something has retrieved the resource (e.g., via a `std::move`) beforehand.

The only suggestion I would make its to use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) when creating the pointer (for exception-safety, and to make the code more idiomatic). Other than that minor detail, it sounds like you've got the right idea.

Comment: Is make_unique a part of the c++11 standard ? I thought it wasn't implemented in the library yet.

Comment: It's part of the C++14 standard, but all the major compilers have already implemented it. If it isn't available on your compiler, you should use this custom implementation provided by Herb Sutter: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Comment: It seems that it's not available in GCC's 4.8 version but it is getting implemented in the 4.9 version.

Comment: Dang, I could have sworn that GCC already had it. Sorry to have misled you. (I do know that Clang and Visual Studio have it.)

Comment: It doesn't matter, I will probably implement it myself until it gets released with the help of that sweet link of yours :L

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned that you can't efficiently move an `sf::Texture`, then don't move an `sf::Texture`. Construct them directly in the map:

```
void ResourceManager::loadTexture(const std::string& file)
{
    assert(mtextures.find(file) == mtextures.end());
    auto& t = mtextures[file];
    try {
        if (!t.loadFromFile(file)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("ResourceManager::load - Failed to load " + file);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        mtextures.erase(file);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and makes me feel dumb. I forgot that the [] operator introduces a new element to the map if there isn't one with the same key already in it, so I thought I could only insert a pair using insert and emplace.

Comment: By the way isn't that supposed to be != in the assert?

Comment: @Veritas `find` returns an iterator to the entry with the given key  (`file`) or `end()` of no such entry exists. The `assert` verifies that the entry we're adding is not present in the map beforehand, just as does `assert(inserted.second)` in the OP.

Comment: When you start getting conditionals wrong you know it's time to go to bed.

Comment: It seems that this version is not that exception-safe when it comes to the loadFromFile function.

Comment: @Veritas Woops, fixed.

Comment: It kind of loses it's elegance this way, doesn't it ?

Comment: Manual exception handling is always inelegant, I figured that writing an RAII class to handle removal from the map would overcomplicate the code (i.e., it would be longer than `loadTexture`). Elegance was never really my goal: I was aiming to preserve the OP's original value semantics for the map without requiring extra copies of the textures.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50986/discussion-between-veritas-and-casey)